# Not getting expected file result using awk

Tags: unix, awk

```
#!/bin/bash
delete_file () {
    for file in processor_list.txt currnet_username.txt unique_username.txt
    do
        if [ -e  $file  ] ;then
            rm $file
        fi
    done
}
delete_file
ps -elf > processor_list.txt ; chmod 755 processor_list.txt
awk '{print $3}' processor_list.txt > currnet_username.txt ; chmod 755 currnet_username.txt
sort -u currnet_username.txt  > unique_username.txt ;chmod 755 unique_username.txt
while read line ; do
    if [ -e  $line.txt ]  ;then
        rm $line.txt
    fi 
    grep $line processor_list.txt >$line.sh ;chmod 755 $line.sh
    awk '{if($4 == "$line") print $0;}' $line.sh > ${line}1.txt ; #mv ${line}1.txt $line.txt;chmod 755 $line.txt
done < unique_username.txt
```

I'm a beginner of unix shell scripting. please suggested, i am not getting expected results in ${line}1.txt.

For example, I have two UID like kplus , kplustp. what is my requirement is find "kplus" string from ps -elf command and create a file as same name like kplus.txt and redirect or move the data whatever found data using grep command.

But  I am getting kplus and kplustp  data in kplus.txt file. I need only kplus value based on UID column from  ps –elf  in  kplus.txt file.

Comment: Jotne's answer is correct in what it discusses. The other part of your problem is that grep doesn't (by default) care about matching whole words. So when you grep for `kplus` it matches both `kplus` and `kplust`. You need to tell it not to do that.

Comment: Good point, @EtanReisner then `grep -w` should make it.

Answer (score 4):

This is wrong way to read variable using `awk`

```
awk '{if($4 == "$line") print $0;}' $line.sh
```

Use:

```
awk '{if($4 == var) print $0;}' var="$line" $line.sh
```

Or shorten to

```
awk '$4==var' var="$line" $line.sh
```

default action is `{print $0}` if no action is specified.

---

If you need to search for the text `$line` escape the `$` in regex

```
awk '$4==/\$line/' $line.sh
```

or in text it should work directly

```
awk '$4=="$line"' $line.sh
```

Comment: Just for clarity the reason the first entry is wrong is because the `$line` is within the external single quotes and therefore does not get expanded by the shell.

Comment: @EtanReisner yes that it true.

Comment: +1 because I didn't know you can do `awk '...' var=something` style assignments. I only knew `awk -v var=some '...'` style, which actually doesn't even work in Solaris, so that's worse in many ways.

Comment: @janos The thing you're saying doesn't work on Solaris is only an issue for old, broken awk (/usr/bin/awk on Solaris). Do not use that awk - use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk or nawk on Solaris instead. Use `-v var=value`. The only time it's appropriate to use `var=value` in the arg list is when you need to change initial FS values between files.

Comment: @Jotne - I don't know what `'$4==/\$line/'` would do as I've never seen RE delimiters `/.../` used in a string (i.e. non-RE) comparison `==`. It MAY be undefined behavior but whether it is or not I'd strongly recommend avoiding using that syntax as it's confusing at best. Actually, thinking about it a bit more, I THINK it's probably short-hand for `'$4==($0 ~ /\$line/)'`, i.e. see if $0 contains $line and compare the 1/0 result of that comparison with $4.